# Entity Framework on a SQL instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Every EF tutorial I've looked at requires LocalDB or SQL Express to be used in a code-first approach with EF.

Is there a way to connect to a traditional SQL DB (2014) instance using code-first EF and have EF create the schema in the DB? Or would I have to connect to a DB with an exsiting matching schema when switching to production?

It's fine to use LocalDB for dev purposes, but when deploying to production, I'd like to plug into an actual and existing SQL DB. Is there a way to do this without plugging into a DB that has had its schema manually made to match the EF models?

Comment: There is no difference between express and a normal install, Have you tried setting the connection string to a real database and seeing what happens?

Comment: I've tried to connect to my localhost instance of a SQL DB and it works fine, but if I update a model, it breaks because the DB schema is not auto-updated by EF (I have to go to Mgmt Studio and tweak the schema to match the EF models).

Comment: How do you update schema of the LocalDb database?

Comment: Please show some code showing how you set your Initialization strategy. (The place where you have `Seed()`)

Comment: @DavidG, I am not using LocalDb (trying to get this to work with a regular SQL DB instance on localhost), but I believe it creates the LocalDb schema from the model classes.

@ScottChamberlain, I am not calling `Seed()` anywhere, I'm just creating a test object and inserting it, then calling `dbContext.SaveChanges()`. If the object has a field that is not in the DB schema, it throws and exception instead of dropping the table/db and auto-creating the schema to match the model classes.

Comment: @Jesse As Scott said, there is no difference between LocalDb and SQL Server. In fact, you can attach the LocalDb files directly into SQL Server and they work. The point of my question was to figure out how your model is updating the database.

Comment: @Jesse Additionally, the only thing that would stop EF from making changes in the database is SQL permissions.

Comment: @DavidG, I understand that there is no difference, but in my specified connection string, I'd like to specify a specific DB to use instead of writing ".\SQLEXPRESS" or something generic like that. I'm trying to plug into an /existing/ SQL DB and have EF auto-update the schema as needed.

Comment: @Jesse Then just use a normal SQL Server connection string.

Comment: @DavidG, I am indeed using a normal SQL connection string. The problem is this: when I connect to my existing localhost SQL DB, then call `dbContext.SaveChanges()` after making an insert using a model that has a property not found in the mappped table, I get an error instead of EF auto-updating the schema. Surely there is a way to get EF to auto-update the DB schema so that it matches the models.

Comment: @Jesse Then we are back to Scott's question about initialisation strategy. If you don't have one, you need to set it up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57714/discussion-between-davidg-and-jesse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using Entity Framework's Code First Migrations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).

Short version:

1) In your DbContext, set the initializer to CreateDatabaseIfNotExists similar to  `Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<YourDbContext>());`

This will allow EF to create the DB if no database exists (the first time the application is run).

2) Next, go to the Package Manager Console, select your Database project (if separate), and enter the command `Enable-Migrations`. This will create some migration scaffolding and an initial migration.

Whenever you change your database model in code from then on, do the following steps:

3) After you've changed your code-first model, go to the Package Manager Console, select the Database project, and type the command `Add-Migration MigrationNameHere` This will scaffold out a new separate migration that can be applied to your database. Note, this command will run for whatever db is in your current connection string config.

4) To apply the migration, and update your database to the new schema, type the command `Update-Database`. If everything goes well, your database will be updated (with data) to the new schema! You should now be able to run your MVC project without db errors.

Keep in mind, this is the very basic version of db-migrations, please try it out on a dummy project first, and of course backup your data. If the changes are complex, or you need to do a special migration of data, you can edit the scaffolded migration code in the Migrations folder created, before doing the Update-Database.

Hope this helps!